# R Data Analysis 'nycflights13'

Tags: r

I need to find all the flights flew to Dallas thus either dest: DAL or DFW. Below is what I get.

```
flights %>%
  filter(dest==c('DAL','DFW'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the key is "either", which means you need a Boolean OR:

```
flights %>%
  filter(dest == 'DAL' | dest == 'DFW'))
```

Another way to do it is with `%in%`:

```
flights %>%
  filter(dest %in% c('DAL','DFW'))
```

Comment: This works and fixed my coding error.